# Is it possible for Google Drive's folder structure to contain a loop?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm currently writing a function to iterate through a Google Drive folder and all sub-files and folders on a Node.js server using the Google Drive v3 API. I know Google Drive allows users to add multiple links to the same file/folder by using Shift + Z, but it does stop users from adding the link inside itself. Despite this, I am left wondering if there is any way this could occur.

[image: Programmer Art]

I would much rather iterate through a tree vs a circular graph.

In short, are we positive circular dependencies don't exist in Google Drive?

Comment: Perhaps a maximum depth is easier to track than full loop detection? Just to be safe.

Comment: they exist in theory, but I've never managed to create one.

Comment: I could do max depth but then I'd be worried about missing some operations.

Comment: It's not a huge deal if I have to do some sort of graph traversal. Just trying to be lazy.

Comment: it's easy to create a loop. just add the same folder to two folders, drive does not prevent it, only team drive prevents it.

Comment: I don't think that creates a loop though. Would you be able to share a folder structure in Drive where you've reproduced this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create one by adding a shared folder (C) to a folder (B) that you had previously shared with someone else who put it in a folder (D) who then shared it with you. Where you add it to your google drive as a folder inside of (C)